# How to add a QComboBox in QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

Now, I need to add a QComboBox in QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget. However, I find the signal-slot do not work.

The code is:

```
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qsurfaceformat.h>
#include <QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget.h>
#include <qcombobox.h>
#include "qboxlayout.h"
class VTKTestWidget :public QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget
{
public:
    VTKTestWidget()
    {
        m_combobox_ = new QComboBox;
        m_combobox_->addItem("item1");
        m_combobox_->addItem("item2");
        QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout;
        layout->addWidget(m_combobox_);
        this->setLayout(layout);
        connect(m_combobox_, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged), this, SLOT(widgetComboboxIndexChangeSlot));
    }

public slots:
    void widgetComboboxIndexChangeSlot(int index)
    {
        std::cout << index << std::endl;
    }
protected:
    QComboBox* m_combobox_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget::defaultFormat());
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    VTKTestWidget* widget = new VTKTestWidget;
    widget->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

When I change the index of QComboBox, the widgetComboboxIndexChangeSlot would not be called.

How can I fix this problem? Or the QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget can not be treated as a normal QWidget?

Any suggestion is appreciated~~~~

------------------------- Update --------------------------------
Finally, thanks to @drescherjm, this problem is solved by:

```
connect(m_combobox_, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(widgetComboboxIndexChangeSlot(int)));
```

Comment: You forgot the `Q_OBJECT` in your `VTKTestWidget`: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT)

Comment: But, it still do not work even I add `Q_OBJECT`.

Comment: `connect(m_combobox_, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged), this, SLOT(widgetComboboxIndexChangeSlot));` line is wrong.

Comment: It should be `connect(m_combobox_, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(widgetComboboxIndexChangeSlot(int)));`

Comment: Thank you very much. It work. It really make me confuzed.